# Binary Search Trees

Tags: trees, binary

Create a binary search tree for these library titles:

A Duck is a Duck

Enslaved by Ducks

Mini Ducks Songbook

Fowl-Weather Friends

Big Dig Ducks

Regarding Ducks and Universes

Domesticated Ducks

Pocketful of Poultry: Chickens, Ducks, Geese, Turkeys

Comment: How would I convert the letters to numbers? would the spaces count as a number?

Comment: Lexicographical order